# Android LEB128 type size

Tags: java, android

I'm confused about LEB128 or Little Endian Base 128 format. In the `AOSP` source code `Leb128.java`, its read function's return type whether signed or unsigned is `int`. I know the the size of `int` in java is 4 bytes aka `32bits`. But the max length of `LEB128` in AOSP is 5 bytes aka `35 bits`. So where are the other lost `3bits`.

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

Each byte of data in LEB only accounts for 7 bits in the actual output - the remaining bit is used to indicate whether or not it's the end.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128):

> To encode an unsigned number using unsigned LEB128 first represent the number in binary. Then zero extend the number up to a multiple of 7 bits (such that the most significant 7 bits are not all 0). Break the number up into groups of 7 bits. Output one encoded byte for each 7 bit group, from least significant to most significant group.

The extra bits aren't so much "lost" as "used to indicate whether or not it's the end of the data".

You can't hope to encode arbitrary 32-bit values and *some* of them taking less than 4 bytes without *some* of them taking more than 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that the extra bit to indicate the end of the data. I confused that in LEB there are `7bits * 5 bytes = 35 bits` mostly. But the return value type is `int` which its size is `32bits`. Now I maybe know that LEB is a format to zip `int`, so there are not any bits lost but extra. Does it right?

Comment: @litao3rd: I'm afraid I didn't really understand your comment - but if you're using data which *mostly* ends up as 5 bytes, LEB is a bad choice. The point is to represent most values in *less than* 4 bytes... otherwise you might as well just use a fixed 4 bytes per value. And yes, if you *do* write a value with 5 bytes, the top 3 bits should be 0.

Comment: I mean in LEB format there are mostly 5 bytes aka 35bits for data. And LEB128 is used to store `int` which size is 32bits. So it's enough to work. I just confused about its size. thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: @litao3rd: It uses *at most* 5 bytes to represent 32 bits, yes. But again, I'd expect it to be chosen for data where most of the values can be represented in 1-3 bytes.